# Equivalent of these commands in the following distros

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, distributions, dpkg

These commands:

```
dpkg -i
apt-get install
apt-get update
apt-get remove
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get purge
```

in these distros:
Opensuse,
Fedora,
Gentoo,
Arch,
Slackware.

Comment: As a heads up, the package managers for all of the distributions you listed are Zypper, Yum, Emerge, Pacman, and Pkgtools/Slackpkg, if you're inclined to look at their manual pages.  Are you looking to switch from Ubuntu or something like that?

Comment: yes, not exactly that, there are many distros based on those that look good to me, Ubuntu has gotten really worse, I'm not gonna use anything ubuntu based when I buy a new machine to install linux on.

Comment: I'm using Arch Linux now (after coming from Ubuntu a couple years ago), and I'm extremely happy with it, if you're looking for recommendations.  There's a bit of a learning curve, and it requires somwhat robust command-line familiarity, but everything is documented incredibly well at wiki.archlinux.org.

Comment: Also, Arch Linux and Gentoo are rolling-release distributions, and do not have `dist-upgrade` analogs.

Comment: There are many Debian-based distros which are not Ubuntu, all of which use Apt.

Comment: Here is everything you need : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Rosetta

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_Rosetta) page, you will get all details .

**Fedora/RHEL/CentOS:**

```
yum install/remove/search/update  package
```

**OpenSuse:**

```
yast2 --install/--remove <package_name>
```

Or

```
zypper                 # to print the list of available global options and commands
zypper help search     # to print help for the search command
zypper lp              # to see what patch updates are needed
zypper patch           # to apply the needed patches
zypper se sqlite       # to search for sqlite
zypper rm sqlite2      # to remove sqlite2
zypper in sqlite3      # to install sqlite3
zypper in yast*        # to install all packages matching 'yast*'
zypper up              # to update all installed packages with newer versions, where possible
```

**Gentoo:**

```
emerge package    # Install
emerge -C package # Remove a package
emerge -s keyword # Search for packages (package names only)
emerge -u package # update the package
```

**Arch**

```
pacman -U package.pkg.tar.xz # Local package install
pacman -Syy                  # Refresh package databases
pacman -Syu                  # Update installed packages
pacman -S package            # Install package
pacman -R package            # Remove package
```

**Slackware**

Check man pages of Pkgtools/Slackpkg

Comment: Thanks, how do i update the repositories, i.e. equivalent of `apt-get update`

Comment: when we use `yum search package` it's first resynchronize the package index files.., not everytime, but first time when new repo added

Comment: `reposync` is used to synchronize a remote YUM repository with a local directory using yum to get the packages, you need to install `yum-utils` package for this command

Comment: Thanks, I am now installing the Arch-based Manjaro to give it a try, the cLI installer is easy for me to navigate, again, thank you guys!